# MySQL matching unicode characters with ascii version

Tags: mysql, select, unicode, match

I'm running MySQL 5.1.50 and have a table that looks like this:

```
organizations | CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

The problem I'm having is that MySQL is matching unicode characters with ascii versions. For example when I search for a word with that contains an 'é', it will match the same word that has an 'e' instead, and vice versa:

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, name FROM `organizations` WHERE `name` = 'Universite de Montreal';
    +-------+-------------------------+
| id    | name                    |
+-------+-------------------------+
| 16973 | Université de Montreal  |
+-------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I get these results both from PHP and the command line console. How can I get accurate matches from my SELECT queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You specified the `name` column as `text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` which tells MySQL to consider **e** and **é** as equivalent in matching and sorting. That collation and `utf8_general_ci` both make a lot of things equivalent.

http://www.collation-charts.org/ is a great resource once you learn how to read the charts, which is pretty easy.

If you want **e** and **é** etc. to be considered different then you must choose a different collation. To find out what collations are on your server (assuming you're limited to UTF-8 encoding):

```
mysql> show collation like 'utf8%';
```

And choose using the collation charts as a reference.

One more special collation is `utf8_bin` in which there are no equivalencies, it's a binary match.

The only MySQL Unicode collations I'm aware of that are not language specific are `utf8_unicode_ci`, `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_bin`. They are rather weird. The real purpose of a collation is to make the computer match and sort as a person from somewhere would expect. Hungarian and Turkish dictionaries have their entries ordered according to different rules. Specifying a collation allows you to sort and match according to such local rules.

For example, it seems Danes consider e and é equivalent but Icelanders don't:

```
mysql> select _utf8'e' collate utf8_danish_ci
    -> = _utf8'é' collate utf8_danish_ci as equal;
+-------+
| equal |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+

mysql> select _utf8'e' collate utf8_icelandic_ci
    -> = _utf8'é' collate utf8_icelandic_ci as equal;
+-------+
| equal |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Another handy trick is to fill a one column table with a bunch of characters you're interested in (it's easier from a script) and then MySQL can tell you the equivalencies:

```
mysql> create table t (c char(1) character set utf8);
mysql> insert into t values ('a'), ('ä'), ('á');
mysql> select group_concat(c) from t group by c collate utf8_icelandic_ci;
+-----------------+
| group_concat(c) |
+-----------------+
| a               |
| á               |
| ä               |
+-----------------+

mysql> select group_concat(c) from t group by c collate utf8_danish_ci;
+-----------------+
| group_concat(c) |
+-----------------+
| a,á             |
| ä               |
+-----------------+

mysql> select group_concat(c) from t group by c collate utf8_general_ci;
+-----------------+
| group_concat(c) |
+-----------------+
| a,ä,á           |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough reply!

Answer (score 8):

Of course, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE BINARY 'namé';
```

Comment: I tried all kinds of collation variants and '%º%' (ordinal indicator, not degree symbol) kept matching things it shouldn't. Saw this and tried it and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

one thing you can do with your query string is to decode it...

```
< ?php
$query="उनकी"; // some Unicode characters
$query=urldecode($query);
$qry= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE books LIKE '%$query%'";

//rest of the code....
?>
```

it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have set collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` which equates accented latin characters.  Additional information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Comment: user825466 did set `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` and this is why MySQL returns matches such as the one in the example that he or she did NOT want.

Comment: @fsb - Yes, I was explaining to the question writer *why* they were seeing the collation.  My reading of the question was that they were unaware of the fact.

Comment: You're both right - I didn't know why, and I also did not want it to happen. I ended up coding around it with PHP, but if the need arises in the future I'll specify the collation in the SELECT statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that you get the requested result using REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP 'namé';
```

But this doesn't help if you try to group exactly by name.