# MySql check for non unicode characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mySql and some of the rows have an é. And when I am running my script to use the values in the mySql it breaks because of this. I am trying to find all the rows that contain an "é" but it doesn't work? Here is what I am trying:

```
SELECT * FROM `Schools_Geocode` WHERE `column` LIKE 'é'
```

How can I find row that contains é

Comment: use this `LIKE '%é%'`

Comment: @Abdulla right. but that returned objects that any e not just é

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql

Comment: check this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552950/mysql-matching-unicode-characters-with-ascii-version