# A strange search result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some website domains in my MySQL database, and I do a search as below:

```
mysql root@localhost:webinfo> SELECT * FROM raw_domains_res WHERE Domain='albumudinle.com';

+-----------------+-------+--------+
| Domain          |   Num |     id |
|-----------------+-------+--------|
| albumudinle.com |     3 | 588242 |
| albümüdinle.com |     2 | 592846 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+

2 rows in set
Time: 0.001s
```

And in Python, they are two different strings. Anyone tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: you have 2 records in your table that are stored with Domain -> "albumudinle.com"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL matching unicode characters with ascii version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552950/mysql-matching-unicode-characters-with-ascii-version)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `Domain` column is a unicode collation, maybe something like `utf8_unicode_ci`? Querying on columns with unicode collation will roll up the non-ascii characters to their ascii counterpart. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) for more info about this. You can avoid this problem by:

1. Change the column collation to a `binary` collation such as `utf8_bin`; or
2. Perform a [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html) query on the column:

   `SELECT * FROM raw_domains_res WHERE Domain = BINARY 'albumudinle.com'`